# How to install CDR-STATS on Exiting CentOS FreeSWITCH Server Manually without Bash Script

Tags: centos, freeswitch

I am trying to install CDR-STATS on Exiting CentOS 6.4 server where  FreeSWITCH is already running well, i read all available documentation and mailing list but i didn;t find any notes where can i install step by step.

Please any one know help me to get ride on it.

I appreciate your support.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

CDR-Stats comes with a script install-all-cdr-stats-freeswitch.sh which will install FreeSWITCH with CDR-Stats. In the scenario where you have already FreeSWITCH installed, you can execute the install-cdr-stats.sh, it will prompt you with a question to know if you want to run an installation for FreeSWITCH or Asterisk.

```
cd /usr/src/ ; wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/Star2Billing/cdr-stats/master/install/install-cdr-stats.sh -O install-cdr-stats.sh ; bash install-cdr-stats.sh
```

I will also advice you to read carefully the install-freeswitch script, cause it does few things apart installing FreeSWITCH for instance configuring it to be used with mongodb_cdr.

https://github.com/Star2Billing/cdr-stats/blob/master/install/install-freeswitch.sh#L166

Comment: Thanks Areski, I did those step before but i am getting error